# google cloud funtion pubsub trigger

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, in-app-billing, google-cloud-pubsub

I'm trying to write the backend part of payment processing for google play in-app purchases.
following google documentation i created a pub/sub topic, activated this topic on play console and im doing first tests.

everything seems to work fine, but there is a small warning message:

> Function returned undefined, expected Promise or value

according to the docs: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/providers_pubsub_.topicbuilder#on-publish

```
Returns PromiseLike<any> | any
```

it is not clear what they are going to do with the return... can i simple return '1'? should all the processing be done inside the promise? there is not much documentation about how it should be

code:

```
exports.dublin = functions.runWith({
    timeoutSeconds: 25,
    memory: '128MB'
}).pubsub.topic('gp-igibo-purchases').onPublish((message) => {
  
  console.log(JSON.stringify(message));
  return 1;
  
});
```

Comment: Please edit the question to show the code of the function that isn't working the way you expect.  Functions should return a promise that resolves when all the async work is complete.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions

Comment: The updated code should work in general conditions. The only point of error visible is if the message is circular array. Try wrapping the code in try-catch block.